# How can I custom order the results from wp_list_categories?

Tags: loop, sort, order, categories

I am using [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) to return (you guessed it) a list of categories within a custom taxonomy.  The `orderby` parameter accepts sorting by ID, name, slug, count, and term_group.  Is there a way that I can custom sort the results?  Ideally I could pass an array of category ID's in the desired order, but obviously I'll have to dig a bit deeper to get this sorted.

Comment: when you say post ids do you mean that you want to get the categories of those posts or do you mean that you want to pass category ids?

Comment: My mistake, I meant category ID's, not post ID's. It's been a long day, ha. Let me fix the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an unused column, term_order, in the wp_term_relationships table that you can use to assign a custom order to the terms within your taxonomy.  The order is set at 0 by default and it will take a custom query to get the order back and another solution to set the order.

Example query:

```
function wpse_order_taxes() {
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->terms t inner join $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt on t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE taxonomy = 'category'  ORDER BY term_order ASC LIMIT 0, 10" );
        $categories = array();
        foreach ( $results as $cat ) {
            array_push( $categories, $cat->slug );
        }
        return $categories;
    }
```

This would give you back an array of terms ordered by the custom order.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the term_order column. I will see if I can get that to work and report back.

Comment: +1 but this also means, that you are hoping, that core won't use it ever ;)

Comment: It would be nice if it got used to order categories.  It's actually used for galleries.  A few trac tickets on it: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9547#comment:7